# Jenkins JIRA Trigger Plugin Only Triggers 1 Job

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jira, jenkins-jira-trigger

I've setup a webhook trigger from JIRA to trigger a Jenkins job.
This works fine for 1 particular Jenkins job, I can see the JIRA content coming in and the test Jenkins job runs fine.
However I can't get any other jobs to run from the webhook. Even if I copy the job that works correctly, that doesn't trigger either and I can't see anyway of debugging the issue.
Can anyone help shed some light on my issue please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you get that one job to trigger other jobs that you need to trigger as downstream jobs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess so, but it's not as clean as I'd hope.
Should the trigger be able to trigger multuple Jenkins jobs though?

Comment: I think that's a good feature, I can't remember if it's been requested before. The plug-in is open-source, so feel free to create PR: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin

Comment: So does this mean the plugin can only trigger 1 Jenkins job at a time?

Comment: Ah I've added more detailed logging to the base of the plugin, and can see that some of our jobs enter the processing function, but then the plugin seems to stop as it doesn't go on to Scheduling build for some reason.... it just stops outputting to the logger, which implies the plugin has stopped

Comment: So if I add anything into my JQL filter, this appears to stop the plugin at that point, I'm not clear why
Jenkins 2.332.3

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin, you can add a Token that will help you specify which job you need to run for a specific webhook.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/